# How do I rename the labels of my individual boxplots in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyr, boxplot

I have created a boxplot for groups in ggplot. Therefore I had to reshape the data frame from a wide into a long format. Now I want to change the labels or names of my individual plots in my graph. I used the function `xlim(labels= c("A", "B")`, which changes the labels, but gives me error messages and the plot is no longer calculated/displayed.

```
    data3 %>% 
      select(Treatment_A, Treatment_B) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "Variable",values_to = "Value") %>%
      ggplot(aes(x= Variable, y = Value, fill = Variable)) +
      stat_boxplot(geom= "errorbar", width= 0.5) +
      geom_boxplot(fill=c("skyblue2", "gold2"))+
      labs(x="Treatment", y="Frequency (total)", title="Treatment comparison")+
      theme_minimal()+
      theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size =10))+
      theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size =10))+
      theme(plot.title=element_text(size = 16))+
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
      stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "errorbar", aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y..),
               width = .75,lwd = 0.7, linetype = "dashed", col = "red") +
      xlim(labels= c("A", "B"))+ # <- This gives me the error
      ylim(0,30)
```

Warning messages:

```
1: Removed 2730 rows containing missing values (stat_boxplot). 
2: Removed 2730 rows containing missing values (stat_boxplot). 
3: Removed 2730 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary). 
4: In max(f) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: Computation failed in `stat_summary()`:
argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
```

I am still very new to R, need the graphic for my master thesis and am grateful for any help. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `xlim` is a shorthand for setting the limits and using `xlim(labels= c("A", "B"))` you are setting the limits of the x scale to be equal `c("A", "B")`, i.e. only observations with an `x` value of `"A"` or `"B"` are included in your plot. All other observations get dropped and that's what the warning are telling to.

To assign labels use the `labels` argument of `scale_x_discrete` instead.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

data3 <- data.frame(
  Treatment_A = runif(100, 0, 30),
  Treatment_B = runif(100, 0, 30)
)

p <- data3 %>%
  select(Treatment_A, Treatment_B) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Variable, y = Value, fill = Variable)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = c("skyblue2", "gold2")) +
  labs(x = "Treatment", y = "Frequency (total)", title = "Treatment comparison") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 10)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  stat_summary(
    fun = mean, geom = "errorbar", aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y..),
    width = .75, lwd = 0.7, linetype = "dashed", col = "red"
  ) +
  ylim(0, 30)
```

First, to reproduce your issue by adding `xlim(labels = c("A", "B"))`:

```
p +
  xlim(labels = c("A", "B"))
#> Warning: The dot-dot notation (`..y..`) was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `after_stat(y)` instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.
#> Warning: Removed 200 rows containing missing values (`stat_boxplot()`).
#> Warning in min(x): no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#> Warning in max(x): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#> Warning in min(diff(sort(x))): no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#> Warning: Removed 200 rows containing missing values (`stat_boxplot()`).
#> Warning: Removed 200 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_summary()`).
#> Warning in max(f): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#> Warning: Computation failed in `stat_summary()`
#> Caused by error in `seq_len()`:
#> ! argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
```

[image]

Using `scale_x_discrete` instead gives the desired result:

```r
p +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("A", "B"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation and improvement, works out perfectly! Highly appreciate it!